# Issues with bibliography -- No special characters

Tags: bibtex

I'm having issues with my bibliography file. I have the following:

```
\documentclass[final,inline]{ieee}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

  \cite{ref11}, \cite{ref12}  

  \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
  \bibliography{bloob}
\end{document}
```

And I've saved `bloob.bib` in the same directory:

```
@inproceedings{
  ref11,
  author = "Eun-Kyu Lee and Sungwon Yang and Oh, S.Y.\ and Gerla, M.",
  Title = "RF-GPS: RFID Assisted Localization in VANETs",
  booktitle ="IEEE 6th International Conference on Mobile Adhoc and Sensor Systems MASS",
  pages = "621-626",
  year = "2009"
}

@article{
  ref12,
  author = "Eun-Kyu Lee and Soon Y.\ Oh and Mario Gerla",
  title = "RFID Assisted Vehicle Positioning in VANETs",
  journal = "Journal of Pervasive and Mobile Computing",
  volume = "8",
  year = "2012",
  pages = "167-179"
}
```

There are two warnings saying `ref11` and `ref12` don't exist. I've tried multiple runs as well.

Comment: Did you run BibTeX? If so, what does the `.blg` file say?

Comment: It works fine for me (although I switched `ieee` to `article`).

Comment: @JosephWright Doesn't TeX Live on Windows do that itself?

Comment: I'm using LatexMk, by the way.

Comment: I doubt its the problem, but it would be more usual to in the `bib` file to have the label on the same line as the type, e.g. `@article{ref12,` without a line break.

Comment: @HameerAbbasi No, you either have to do it using a script or by hand.